# How to disable back press action for an intent?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity which makes use of `KeyguardManager`.

The intention is to disallow the user to use the app, if they are unable to successfully supply their credentials.

Though the keyguard intent appears at the start of the app, pressing the device back button moves the intent away, showing the activity which started it.

Overriding the `onBackPressed` does not seem to help, as it isn't associated with the intent.

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {

  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if (km.isKeyguardSecure()) {
      setShowWhenLocked(true);
      Intent i = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("Authentication required", "password");
      startActivityForResult(i, CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you checking credentials directly in the activity that is supposed to be protected? Why not introduce an Auth activity responsible solely for authenticating the user or telling him that he needs to login?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is that intended to answer my question?

Comment: Asking to know if you business logic has some limitation that prevents from doing that because I would say it’s a common pattern

Comment: I have no restrictions as of now, please feel free to give an answer. I am a beginner of android programming, so maybe I am unaware of the common problems in the area.

Comment: the right way would be to create a login activity that will launch the keyguard intent and show error if user didn't authenticate. With using finish on the first activity , if user enters the right credentials then your keyguard screen will be dismissed and user just exits the app @113408 gives you a valid suggestion

Answer (score 1):

What if you use finish() after startActivity() ?

EDIT:

Add finish() on your onActivityResult() if the pattern is false.

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` != `startActivity()`. so what if the users provides a valid pattern?

Comment: In your onActivityResult() you recreate your precedent activity with a specific value in the intent which says that user provided a valid patent ? I don't know, I'm just trying to propose things ..

Comment: Hey could you please add your comment to the answer?

Comment: I just added finish() in my onActivityResult() if the pattern was false.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be done using a "Staging" `Activity`. For example, you can have a `LoginActivity` that will check if the user is authenticate or not then from there decide where to redirect him.

The `LoginActivity` should look something like this, of course you need to adapt it to your business logic :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION = 24;
    private boolean isFirstLaunch = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        isFirstLaunch = false;
        //startActivityForResult With your intent to authenticate the user
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION){
            Log.i("LOGIN", "return from key guard");
            //Check the data and decide if you redirect the user to main activity or not
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!isFirstLaunch){
            Log.i("LOGIN", "resume not first launch");
            // the user tried to cancel the authentication either present him with the authentication process again or finish() the activity
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, N/B: Overriding the `onBackPressed` does help only **when you create a conditional statement controlled by a boolean variable** in the `onBackPressed` method and call it in the `onActivityResult` i.e when the resultCode != RESULT_OK. Another option is to exit the app when resultCode != RESULT_OK (moveTaskToBack(true))  Here is what I mean below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == INTENT_AUTHENTICATE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //do something you want when pass the security

        } else //resultCode != RESULT_OK
            //Option 1 Ensure you override onBackPressed() with a conditional 
            //statement controlled by a boolean variable.
            onBackPressed();

        //Option 2
        moveTaskToBack(true); //Exit app when a user click the back button.

    }
}
```